# Why is web deploy looking for 32 bit version of dacpac when only 64 bit is installed

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, webdeploy, dacpac

I have a web forms web app; when I try to publish it using Visual Studio 2015 web deploy with database selected it returns error this error:

```
ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
```

but i have all the required libraries installed. On debugging using Process Monitor I noted web deploy looking for x86 version of dacpac dll but I have only 64bit installed.

Do I need to install x86 versions as well to make it work?

Comment: @StevenGreen Do you the solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the scriptdom:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

(change to point to whatever version of the scriptdom and gacutil you have on your machine / you want to use)

From:

https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/977

Comment: I will give it a try